# Is there a more efficient way to replace these multiple IF statements?

Tags: c++, if-statement

I'm trying to make this part of my program run more efficiently and I'm not sure what the best way is to optimize this block of code so its quicker

An input to the system ranging from 1 to -1 (it's sensitive, I need fine detail). I am trying to compute an output which is called `yaw_cmd_v` (yaw commanded voltage)

```
//Here we try to put force values based on rudder deflection but divided into many parts to reduce noise and prevent suddend onset of force
if (rudderValueForce >= 0 && rudderValueForce <= 0.05)      { yaw_CMND_V = -rudderValueForce * 0; }
if (rudderValueForce >= 0.05 && rudderValueForce <= 0.1)    { yaw_CMND_V = -rudderValueForce * 5; }
if (rudderValueForce >= 0.1 && rudderValueForce <= 0.15)    { yaw_CMND_V = -rudderValueForce * 10; }
if (rudderValueForce >= 0.15 && rudderValueForce <= 0.2)    { yaw_CMND_V = -rudderValueForce * 15; }
if (rudderValueForce >= 0.2 && rudderValueForce <= 0.25)    { yaw_CMND_V = -rudderValueForce * 20; }
if (rudderValueForce >= 0.25 && rudderValueForce <= 0.3)    { yaw_CMND_V = -rudderValueForce * 25; }
if (rudderValueForce > 0.3 && rudderValueForce <= 0.5)      { yaw_CMND_V = -rudderValueForce * 50; }
if (rudderValueForce > 0.5 && rudderValueForce <= 0.7)      { yaw_CMND_V = -rudderValueForce * 60; }
if (rudderValueForce > 0.7 && rudderValueForce <= 1)        { yaw_CMND_V = -rudderValueForce * 70; }

//Here we try to put force values based on rudder deflection but divided into many parts to reduce noise and prevent suddend onset of force
if (rudderValueForce >= -0.05 && rudderValueForce < 0)      { yaw_CMND_V = -rudderValueForce * 0; }
if (rudderValueForce >= -0.1 && rudderValueForce < -0.05)   { yaw_CMND_V = -rudderValueForce * 5; }
if (rudderValueForce >= -0.15 && rudderValueForce < -0.1)   { yaw_CMND_V = -rudderValueForce * 10; }
if (rudderValueForce >= -0.20 && rudderValueForce <- 0.15)  { yaw_CMND_V = -rudderValueForce * 15; }
if (rudderValueForce >= -0.25 && rudderValueForce <- 0.20)  { yaw_CMND_V = -rudderValueForce * 20; }
if (rudderValueForce >= -0.3 && rudderValueForce <- 0.25)   { yaw_CMND_V = -rudderValueForce * 25; }
if (rudderValueForce >= -0.5 && rudderValueForce <- 0.3)    { yaw_CMND_V = -rudderValueForce * 50; }
if (rudderValueForce >= -0.7 && rudderValueForce <- 0.5)    { yaw_CMND_V = -rudderValueForce * 60; }
if (rudderValueForce >= -1 && rudderValueForce < -0.7)      { yaw_CMND_V = -rudderValueForce * 70; }
```

Comment: Just draw the function on a piece of paper.  What does it look like?  A parabola perhaps?

Comment: It would help if you describe where all these numbers come from. If there is a formula, then it'll likely make the solution trivial. Comment about your current code: instead of all these duplicate comparison you want to store thresholds in an array and find the right multiplier in a for-loop.

Comment: Optimization needs context. What problem are you solving?

Comment: If the tests are mutually exclusive, you could use an `else if` instead of an `if`.  That will avoid checking unnecessary conditions.

Comment: it's easy to make the if blocks cleaner, but to make the program `run more efficiently`  you probably need to change the outside context as well. For example it may be better to use fixed-point instead of floating-point, especially on embedded systems

Comment: You have overlapping ranges.  For instance, when `rudderValueForce == 0.05` you first do one thing and then you do something else that cancels the first thing you did.  Get rid of the overlapping ranges, and then consider letting the compiler do the optimizing.

Comment: Note that the upper bounds of one range is the same as the lower bound of the next. Arrange the ifs correctly and you can take advantage of that. The statements that fail will fall though into the next. ie if it's not greater than the highest bound, test to see if it's greater than the next highest. Rinse, repeat.

Answer (score 1):

You may put all your data into the data structure to avoid it getting scattered around your code and use a single `if` in a loop no matter how many data points you have:

```
float limits[][2] = {
    { 0.05, 0.0 }, { 0.1, 5.0 }, { 0.15, 10.0 }, { 0.2, 15.0 }, { 0.25, 20.0 },
    { 0.3, 25.0 }, { 0.5, 50.0 }, { 0.7, 60.0 }, { 1.0, 70.0 }
}

float sign = rudder / abs(rudder);
float value = abs(rudder);

float result = 0.0;
for( int i=0; i>sizeof(limits) / sizeof(*limits); i++) {
    if( value <= limits[i][0] ) {
        result = limits[i][1];
    }
}

return - rudder * result * sign;
```

Comment: Use `std::abs()` or you are truncating floating point to int.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to remove the AND, which means each check would not have to be of two items, except for the first one. But the below means every if statement is evaluated, even if a match was found previously.

```
//Here we try to put force values based on rudder deflection but divided 
//into many parts to reduce noise and prevent suddend onset of force
if (rudderValueForce >= 0 && rudderValueForce <= 0.05)      { yaw_CMND_V = -rudderValueForce * 0; }
if (rudderValueForce <= 0.1)    { yaw_CMND_V = -rudderValueForce * 5; }
if (rudderValueForce <= 0.15)    { yaw_CMND_V = -rudderValueForce * 10; }
if (rudderValueForce <= 0.2)    { yaw_CMND_V = -rudderValueForce * 15; }
if (rudderValueForce <= 0.25)    { yaw_CMND_V = -rudderValueForce * 20; }
if (rudderValueForce <= 0.3)    { yaw_CMND_V = -rudderValueForce * 25; }
if (rudderValueForce <= 0.5)      { yaw_CMND_V = -rudderValueForce * 50; }
if (rudderValueForce <= 0.7)      { yaw_CMND_V = -rudderValueForce * 60; }
if (rudderValueForce <= 1)        { yaw_CMND_V = -rudderValueForce * 70; }
```

It might be better to create a function or method that returns as soon as an if statement has set yaw_CMND_V. Then all the if statements do not have to be evaluated, like so:

```
int setYaw_CMND_V (float rudderValueForce) {
    if (rudderValueForce >= 0 && rudderValueForce <= 0.05)      { 
        return -rudderValueForce * 0; 
    }
    if (rudderValueForce <= 0.1)    { 
        return -rudderValueForce * 5; 
    }
    if (rudderValueForce <= 0.15)    { 
        return -rudderValueForce * 10; 
    }
    // ... 
}
```

Comment: Change the `if`s after the first one to `else if` and it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You have balanced ranges so you don't need to check for 2 different conditions, just take the absolute value and work with it. And as others said, you check some boundaries twice (like `rudderValueForce <= 0.05` and `rudderValueForce >= 0.05`) which is unnecessary and sometimes results in the wrong value. Just check one boundary at once, from ascending or descending order

```
auto v = std::abs(rudderValueForce);
if (v > 1)
    return; // invalid value, do nothing
else if (v > 0.7)
    yaw_CMND_V = -rudderValueForce * 70;
else if (v > 0.5)
    yaw_CMND_V = -rudderValueForce * 60;
else if (v > 0.3)
    yaw_CMND_V = -rudderValueForce * 50;
else
    yaw_CMND_V = -rudderValueForce * (std::ceil(v/0.05) - 1);
```

The ranges below 0.3 have the same width (0.05) so it can be simplified like above without the need to use separate if blocks. `ceil` needs to be used because your range looks like (0.25, 0.3]. If the range is [0.25, 0.3) as most expected the it'll be a lot simpler: `yaw_CMND_V = -rudderValueForce * int(rudderValueForce/0.05)`. Similarly the ranges (0.3, 0.5] and (0.5, 0.7] can also be merged into a single formula

```
-rudderValueForce*(std::ceil((v - 0.3)/0.2)*10 + 40)
```

However depending on your platform it may be very expensive to do a division, so you may want to split into separate cases for v > 0.25, v > 0.2, v > 0.15...

That said, to optimize the code more context is needed, as mentioned in the comment